# How to set defaults/main.yml value dynamically from tasks/main.yml in ansible

Tags: ansible

Populating defaults/main.yml variable dynamically from tasks/main.yml file.

content of defaults main.yml-

```
username:
password:
```

contents of tasks/main.yml -

```
- name: Get username and password
  shell: python some_script.py
  register: result
```

Now, the result contains my user name and password. Is there any easy way i can update that username and password inside defaults/main.yml ?

```
output should be 
username: bob
password: getmein
```

Currently we are doing this like

```
- name: Retrieve username
  shell: echo {{ item | regex_replace('^.*:(.*)$', 'username:\\1')  }} >> playbooks/defaults/main.yml
  with_items: result.stdout_lines[1]
```

Just wanted to know if there is an easy way to do it , apart from using lineinfile.

if a variable is set in defaults/main.yml , we can directly use it by {{ username }}. But how to set the variable in reverse direction dynamically ?

Comment: Why do you need to write it into `defaults/main.yml`? Why not set it as a fact in the playbook/role (and use the `no_log` parameter to hide output if desired)? Defaults are going to be the lowest on the Ansible precedence scale, and I can't imagine a scenario where you'd want to hardcode a password into a role's defaults. Ideally, you'd put passwords and sensitive material in a  group or host variable file encrypted by `ansible-vault`.

Comment: Because ansible has long-noted issues with establishing dynamic defaults, meaning you can't do conditional includes on defaults files.  The `set_fact` and `include_vars` methods both override playbook and inventory level vars.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way to read user input is to use Ansible Prompts (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_prompts.html). That way, you won't need to invoke scripts to read user input.

```
---
- hosts: all
  vars_prompt:
    - name: username
      prompt: "enter username"
      private: no
    - name: password
      prompt: "enter password"
      private: yes

  tasks:
    - name: print
      debug:
        msg: "username = {{ username }}, password = {{ password }}"
```